# how to strongly type react component in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create strongly typed base class for react `Component` including `RouteComponentProps`. What I'd like to achieve is something like this:

```
import * as React from "react";

interface IDetailsModel {
    show: string;
}

interface IComponentProps<TParams, TProps> extends ReactRouter.RouteComponentProps<TParams, {}>, TProps {
}

class ComponentBase<TParams, TProps> extends React.Component<IComponentProps<TParams, TProps>, {}> {

}

class Details extends ComponentBase<{ id: number }, { show: string; }> {
    render() {
        var show = this.props.show;
        var id = this.props.params.id;
        return (
            <div className="container"></div>
        );
    }
}
```

This is not working, because I `IComponentProps` can't extend `TProps` in a way I wanted it to.

When I substitute TProps with concrete interface in IComponentProps definition like this, everything works:

```
interface IComponentProps<TParams, TProps> extends ReactRouter.RouteComponentProps<TParams, {}>, IDetailsModel{
}
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) should do it:

```
interface IComponentProps<TParams> extends ReactRouter.RouteComponentProps<TParams, {}> {}

class ComponentBase<TParams, TProps> extends React.Component<IComponentProps<TParams> & TProps, {}> {}

class Details extends ComponentBase<{ id: number }, { show: string; }> {
    render() {
        var show = this.props.show;
        var id = this.props.params.id;
        return (
            <div className="container"></div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: It did worked, thanks a lot. Funny thing is I've tried this before, but looks like there is an issue with ReSharper reporting this as incorrect. After your answer I've checked with ReSharper turned off and it worked.